# Difference between rake assets:precompile and rake assets:clobber

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone please tell me the difference between rake assets:precompile and rake assets:clobber. really its a great confusion.

Comment: compile creates all the assets, clobber removes them

Answer (score 54):

You can precompile the assets in app/assets using `rake assets:precompile`, and remove older compiled assets using `rake assets:clean`. The `rake assets:clean` task allows for rolling deploys that may still be linking to an old asset while the new assets are being built.
If you want to clear public/assets completely, you can use `rake assets:clobber`.

`rake assets:clean       # Remove old compiled assets`

`rake assets:clobber     # Remove compiled assets`

`rake assets:precompile  # Compile all the assets named in config.assets.precompile`

Answer (score 7):

Note: `rake assets:clobber` also removes the assets directory completely.

To get the info on any rake tasks try this :

```
rake --describe | grep assets
```

This returns all the answers.

```
rake assets:clean[keep]
   Remove old compiled assets
rake assets:clobber
   Remove compiled assets
rake assets:environment
rake assets:precompile
  Compile all the assets named in config.assets.precompile
```

Comment: or just `rake -T assets`

Answer (score 3):

the command `rake assets:clobber` removes/deletes all compiled assets. Whilst the command `rake assets:precompile` creates the compiled assets listed on parameter `config.assets.precompile`.

Please have a read on [Rake's documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rake) for further information on it